# как я могу узнать какими методами обладает request параметр в aiohttp web server

Tags: python, python-3.x, аннотации, aiohttp

хочу узнать какие методы есть у request в aiohtpp или какая есть аннотация у request(нужно чтобы в ide были видны методы)?
мне нужно из get запроса получать логин обрабатывать его

Comment: Есть документация ;) ну или `help(request)`

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что можно использовать:

```
dir(request)
```

Он вам выдаст все атрибуты и методы объекта.

Источник: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/dir

Answer (score 0):

аннотация для ide `request: aiohttp.web.Request`

Comment: Это ответ , потому что я спашивал, какая есть аннотация иои методы, в данном  случае  я показал  что обьект requests и ему такую аннотацию и через ide я могу увидеть  , что у request  есть такие-то методы

Comment: Я подправил вопрос если он покозался некорректным